# Why are there two leaf nodes in this B-Tree lookup?

Tags: database, indexing, tree, nodes, b-tree

In this

[image]

graphic, we are looking up employee_id 123 and subsidary_id 20 in a B-Tree (from a tutorial on database indexes). There are two leaf nodes branching off the tree. Is this purely demonstration, or is there something I'm missing, as I would think that the only leaf node that would need to be checked would be the top one, as it has employee_id max 123 and subsidary_id max 27.

Comment: Erm, what about the nodes that are *not* 123?  Aren't you going to store those in the tree as well?

Comment: Right, but why would it even follow the `125 | 30` in the first place? `123 | 27` *will* contain `123 | 20`, so I don't understand why it would be looking at `125 | 30`

Comment: It wouldn't, but why does that preclude you from showing that node in the diagram?  I think you might be misreading the illustration; the arrows indicate pointers, not data flow or program flow.

Comment: I think you're probably correct, @rb612.  There's no need to look at the node pointed at by (123,18) as that key is too small, and there's no need to look beyond (123, 27) because the highest value is bigger than the key, so the key can only be on the one page.

Comment: True - my original question was: is this just showing the extra leaf node for the sake of demonstration, or is it actually diagramming how the B-Tree would be searched. @RobertHarvey, I think that answered my question then! I thought it was showing data flow, but rather just a demonstration of the surrounding leaf node, correct?

Comment: It is a diagram of a tree, not a diagram of a lookup.

Comment: That distinction helped, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram itself isn't showing the *actions* of that particular search, rather it's showing a localised portion of the tree, so I wouldn't read too much into it for the specific query.

You're absolutely correct in that searching for the key `123-20`, you never need to follow the link to the second leaf node (either through the hierarchical link from the left, or the sequential link from above).

However (and this is hard to tell without seeing the source material), it's quite likely that this diagram may be used for something else as well.

The fact that it shows links between consecutive leaf nodes means that it would be quite easy to use the index lookup to locate a specific entry, then sequentially process them.

By that I mean a query like "give me every record with an employee ID of 123", or "give me all records with an employee ID between `123` and `456`", or "give me all records in employeeID/subsidiaryID order".

All those queries would entail finding a specific record using the hierarchical path (though the final one may have a quicker path direct to the first record), then following the sequential path for subsequent records.

In addition, the fact that the subsidiary IDs of `20` are both red means that it would be an ideal opportunity to educate the reader on the fact that the `employee-subsidiary` index is not necessarily the best one for all queries. In other words, an efficient query "give me all records from subsidiary `20`" would be better with another index (one containing simply the subsidiary ID).

That'd be my best guess, it would be worthwhile looking at the tutorial to see if that diagram is used for something else.

---

Of course, it *could* be that the person putting together the tutorial couldn't be bothered creating a new graphic so simply used one from a different question, or an earlier iteration of the tutorial :-) I've been guilty of that before.